# how to call php through java script in .apk

Tags: php, javascript, android, webview

How to call the php through javascript in apk , i am using webwiew and html5 javascript  and jquery

I want to retrieve the  json data from  php

```
function ajaxFunction() {
    DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    httpclient.addRequestInterceptor(new RequestAcceptEncoding());
    httpclient.addResponseInterceptor(new ResponseContentEncoding());
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://www.smartcloudinfo.com/game/RainbowTreasure(IPAD)/RT_IPADV1.0.40/json.php");
        try {
            // Add your data
            List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("line_value",20));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("stake_value",0.2));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("balance_value",updated_Balance));  
            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
            // Execute HTTP Post Request
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
             alert("found"+HttpResponse response);
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        }
     }
```

Comment: I know it is confusing for many people so I'm curious, do you understand that php is server side while javascript is client side?  So you cannot call php function from javascript.  You can use ajax to execute a call to the server and get the data back, but you don't get to just call the php function.

Comment: Sorry I may be confusing something here.  when you say javascript do you actually mean Java, as in Java for apk?  The code you posted looks a lot like Java, except the function declaration looks like php or javascript.  I may be way off base here due to the erroneous flag "javascript".

Comment: i am creating the .APK file of html 5 game by using  ECLIPSE SOFTWARE  in that i have called the php though JavaScript by using AJAX BUT  i didn't get response from the server.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).  Jquery has a built in functionality to make ajax calls.  Especially if you want to post your answer in [json](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/), there is also a call in jquery to do such things.

Here is a simple sample from the jquery page:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "test.html",
  context: document.body
}).done(function() {
  $(this).addClass("done");
});
```

Or for JSON:

```
$.getJSON("test.js", { name: "John", time: "2pm" }, function(json) {
    alert("JSON Data: " + json.users[3].name);
    });
```

Comment: my problem  is that i have to call the php in andriod through javascript  to fetch the json data

Comment: i am succsfull in getiing the jsondata through ajax  but php is not working  in eclipse software , while creating apk